# Stateless AjaxFallbackButton?

Tags: java, wicket

I tried to google for info on this, but could not find anything.

We are in the process of upgrading an application (webshop) from Wicket 6 to 8, mostly because we needed support for stateless ajax.
This has been relatively painless and making ajax components stateless has been pretty easy. Until I came to AjaxFallbackButtons.

For most of the ajax components, making them stateless is as simple as overriding getStatelessHint() and returning true. But this does not seem to work for AjaxFallbackButton. Looking at the source, I see why: The constructor adds a new AjaxFormSubmitBehavior in a way that does not allow overriding getStatelessHint().

Is this by design? If so, why? And is there a way to make them stateless, other than implementing them from scratch?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have spotted a problem with AjaxFallbackButtons. Unlike the other Ajax components AjaxFallbackButtons can not make the inner AjaxFormSubmitBehavior stateless. This is definitely something we will fix.

Comment: Aha! I had a suspicion that was the case.. :-) We changed to AjaxButton (probably won't be a problem for >99% of our users)